# What background is needed to understand lattices?

Tags: cryptography

I'm trying to read the paper *Finding a Small Root of a Bivariate Integer Equation; Factoring with High Bits Known* but the subject matter is over my head.

I have an academic background in Applied Mathematics but I have not applied that knowledge in a while.

Here is my current study plan:

- Essence of Linear Algebra (3blue1brown) - study for 2 days
- [Understanding Linear Algebra](https://understandinglinearalgebra.org/chap1.html) - study for 3 days
- [Abstract Algebra](https://yewtu.be/playlist?list=PLi01XoE8jYoi3SgnnGorR_XOW3IcK-TP6) - study for 2 days
- [Number Theory](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-785-number-theory-i-fall-2021/) - 4 days to study lectures + do homework
- [Lecture notes on lattices](https://cims.nyu.edu/%7Eregev/teaching/lattices_fall_2004/) - study for 5 days

After this, I would actually begin to read academic papers about lattices by Don Coppersmith. Do you think this is a good enough background to understand his papers? Do you have any other thoughts or suggestions?

How should one best prepare themselves to understand the papers of Don Coppersmith about lattices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't tell us the level of your applied mathematics background. That said, I doubt that you can learn what you need to read Coppersmith's papers in just 16 days of bottom up work from those sources. In particular, I am skeptical about video instruction in basic linear and abstract algebra.

I would suggest that you try to work top down. Start with a paper you want to read, and work backwards to understand each idea that's new to you.

Comment: working top down can be practically useful but can always leave a beginner with too-shaky foundations

Comment: @FShrike True. But starting with the the foundation can lead to overstudying that takes so much time you lose track of what you're trying to understand. Any good strategy will be a mix of top down and bottom up, depending on the individual.